# Unable to initiate ajax call from jquery

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am new to ajax and jquery and trying to place an ajax call in my code. But below are the error messages I get when placing alerts:

1. jqxhr.status = 404
2. thrown error = Not Found
3. jqxhr.statusText = Not Found
4. request = undefined
5. error = undefined

**What I want to do:**
Open a modal dialog with just a Fancy text box (Tinymce) on click of an "Edit gif". After the contents are edited in the textbox, and the "Save" button in the modal dialog is clicked, initiate an ajax call to save the contents in the Database.

**What is happening:**
The modal dialog opens correctly, I am able to see that the "data" part for the ajax call is populated correctly (placed alerts to confirm). I believe the url is also correct. If I type the url in a browser, the control does go to my servlet as per web.xml (Sysout in Servlet gets printed). But somehow, the ajax call never goes through to the server after click of "Save" button. Will be really great if one of you can help me out here, will greatly appreciate it. My JSP (copied what I feel is relevant alone):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sis.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#dialog-form2").dialog({
                autoOpen: false, width: 500, modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function() {
                        tinymce.get("stChallenge").setContent(tinyMCE.get("edChallenge").getContent());
                        alert($("#ChalId").val());
                        alert(tinyMCE.get("edChallenge").getContent());
                        var xhr =
                                $.ajax({
                            url: "/AjaxServlet?method=updateChal&keyword=dummy",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {
                                CommentId: $("#ChalId").val(),
                                challenge: tinyMCE.get("edChallenge").getContent()
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                alert("Success :" + result);
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                            error:function (jqxhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, request, error) {
                                alert('jqxhr.status = ' + jqxhr.status + '\n' + 'thrown error = ' + thrownError + '\n' + 'jqxhr.statusText = '  + jqxhr.statusText + '\n' +
                                    'request = ' + request + '\n' + 'error = ' + error);
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                }
            });
            $("#Edit2")
                    .click(function() {
                $("#dialog-form2").dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#edChallenge", theme: "modern", 
            plugins: [
            ],
            image_advtab: false
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#stChallenge", theme: "modern", readonly: true, toolbar: "false", menubar: "false",
            plugins: [
            ],
            image_advtab: false
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <c:set var="model" value="${sessionScope.model}" />
    <html:form action="managePerf.do?method=showPerf" method="post"  styleId="ManagePerfForm">
        <html:errors/>
        Date: <html:text property="rankDate" styleId="datepicker" name="ManagePerfForm" />
        <html:submit value="Go" styleClass="input button"/>
        <fieldset>                              
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="dialog-form2" title="Edit Challenges">
                            <form>
                                <textarea cols="75" rows="50" id="edChallenge">${comments}</textarea>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <label>Challenges</label>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Edit2">
                            <img src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/Edit.gif' height="32" width="32"/>
                        </a>
                        <div id="dTextBox" class="ui-widget">
                            <textarea cols="75" rows="15" id="stChallenge" readonly="true">${comments}</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="ChalId" value=${CommentId} />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </html:form>
</body>
```

Comment: it means that the resource url `/AjaxServlet` is invalid?

Comment: Check the URL. The URL resource that you are trying to get does not exits at the server side.

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP Said he confirmed that the URL is correct and he has tested it.

Comment: If I type the url in a browser by appending it to context path, the control does go to the Servlet class. I believe that this implies the url is correct?

Comment: My web.xml is as follows:
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>xxx.xxxxx.xxx.servlet.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AjaxServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: All, I actually feel very silly now. I made the mistake of including a "/" at the beginning of the url, which is really the reason for this error. After removing the leading "/", the code works now.

Comment: Thanks very much, ArunPJohny, Sashwat, Jaydeep Patel.